# Webdatarocks - Difference from two date

Tags: webdatarocks

I would calculate difference from 2 date in some dataset? Is it Possibile?
Another calculate is age?
One date is in the dataset and diff with today
Is it Possibile?
Im test calculate formula but I not have found nothing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the today's date in milliseconds to the variable, for example:

```
var today = new Date().getTime();
```

Then, use this variable in the calculated value. Feel free to check the following code snippet illustrating such an approach:

```js
var today = new Date().getTime();
var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
  container: "#wdr-component",
  toolbar: true,
  height: 490,
  report: {
    dataSource: {
      data: getData()
    },
    slice: {
      rows: [
        {
          uniqueName: "Date"
        }
      ],
      measures: [
        {
          uniqueName: "Year difference",
          formula: `(${today}-max(\"Date\")) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25)`,
          caption: "Year difference"
        }
      ]
    },
    formats: [
        {
            name: "",
            decimalPlaces: 0,
        }
    ],
    options: {
      grid: {
        type: "flat"
      }
    }
  }
});

function getData() {
  return [
    {
      Date: {
        type: "date string"
      }
    },
    {
      Date: "2002-01-22",
      Income: 174
    }
  ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.toolbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webdatarocks.com/latest/webdatarocks.js"></script>
<div id="wdr-component"></div>
```